# $\nabla \times \underline{v}$ - Results in a vector perpendicular to these two vectors?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, cross-product

Say $v = -y\hat{i} + x\hat{j}$

If we take the cross product of $\underline{v}$ with $\nabla$ we get

$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\frac{d}{dx} & \frac{d}{dy} & \frac{d}{dz} \\
-y & x & 0 \end{array} \right|$

$= 2k$

So as the cross product of two vectors gives a vector that is perpendicular to those two vectors, the results of $2k$ seems to be saying that $\nabla$ is some vector with non-zero $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ components and a zero $\hat{k}$ component.

But $\nabla = \frac{d}{dx}\hat{i} + \frac{d}{dy}\hat{j} + \frac{d}{dz}\hat{k}$ doesn't give any indication of the magnitude of the $\hat{i}, \hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ components. So I don't understand how $\nabla \times \underline{v}$ resulted in vector of $2k$?

Answer (score 1):

It's a useful mnemonic to remember that the curl is given by a rule formally similar to the formal determinant rule giving the cross product of two vectors, enough that we often denote $\nabla \times X := \mathrm{curl} X$ but that's all it is, a mnemonic; in particular $\nabla$ is neither a vector nor a vector field. When you "evaluate the determinant" in this mnemonic, you *apply* the (partial) derivatives in the middle row to the corresponding functions in the last row. As you noted, the $\hat{k}$-component of the curl is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-y) = 2$$

and the other components are zero, so

$$\mathrm{curl} (-y \hat{i} + x \hat{j}) = 2 \hat{k}.$$